# How did they sacrifice fresh grain for Sukkos, during sabattical and Yoval years?

Tags: korban, sukkot, shmita, yovel

I seem to remember a commandment, specific to Succos, of a sacrifice of fresh grain. While reading this week (Behar) about the sabbatical (shmita) years, a congregant posed the question of what they did about the commandment of a sacrifice of "fresh grain" during those years (and of course, also during the Yovel year).

We did note that it was permitted to gather from un-owned fields, but can you bring a sacrifice gathered in that way?